# Move hdd to other laptop, need Win7 reinstall?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, operating-systems, thinkpad

A Thinkpad T61p died (motherboard), I think hdd is ok.

I then mounted the hdd in a Thinkpad R61i; after hardware change warning, it gave BSOD and instantly shut down.

Is it possible to maintain the Windows installation on this disk? 
In case how can I best make this happen?

EDIT: I have a full Windows 7 license (not OEM).

Comment: @AcePL; Not duplicate, my pc is dead, hence methods given not achievable.

Comment: If you can boot in safe mode, then remove all custom drivers, and this may remove the BSOD. But if (as is likely) you have an OEM licence you will need to purchase a new licence key, though you will have saved yourself the hassle of setting up the new machine as you want it, including reinstalling all your applications.

Comment: @AFH; It's not OEM license, I should have mentioned. I'll try that.

Comment: @bretddog - Disregard the current answers.  It is extremely trivial to use software to restore an image of the HDD to dissimilar hardware.  Most of the software sold that will image your hdd does this.  Most free HDD image software does not.

Comment: So where's your answer, Ramhound?  Imaging the hard disk *is* trivial, as is moving an HDD from one machine to another, but when Windows starts, it'll still decide it's on a different computer and refuse to run.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: Ramhound is talking about imaging programs that modify the HAL or sysprep.

Comment: Again trivial and without the author doing research I am not that inclined to post an answer

Comment: @Ramhound Not everyone who asks a question here is a fully up-to-date guru in their chosen OS, *nor should they be*, and I (at least) wouldn't expect an ordinary user to have any idea how to look for HAL-modifying disk image software.  I've used Windows since 1990, before switching to Linux two years ago, and I'd never heard there were products that would do this...

Comment: @ZeissIkon - You asked why I wasn't submitting an answer.  So I shared my reason.  You used Windows for 25+ years and you never heard of [SysPrep](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940(v=ws.10).aspx)?  Look I am not holding the lack of knowlege against anyone beyond the fact I am not going to submit an answer to a question that does not interest me.  However, If I read something that I feel needs to have a technical point corrected, I am going to do so because I cannot stand wrong infomormation existing on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Something like [Acronis Universal Restore](https://kb.acronis.com/content/2149) might help in this case:

> **Acronis Universal Restore** is the unique technology developed in
>   Acronis that allows changing Windows Hardware Abstraction Layer
>   (HAL.dll) and device drivers.
>
> It is designed to allow a machine to boot its operating system
>   initially after a restoration/deployment of an image to hardware that
>   is different from the one it was taken from, and then proceed with the
>   installation of other drivers and configuration.
>
> Acronis Universal Restore allows changing Windows Hardware Abstraction
>   Layer (HAL.dll) and install mass storage boot device drivers into the
>   system.
>
> Part of the recovery process, It installs boot device drivers (e.g.
>   hard drive or RAID controller drivers) into the system, so that the
>   operating system can boot from this boot device. If there are proper
>   NIC drivers present in the folder with the drivers, Acronis Universal
>   Restore will copy them into the restored system and will schedule
>   their installation on Windows boot-up.
>
> **(!)** All the other drivers (e.g. video and sound card drivers, plug and play drivers) are not installed by Acronis Universal Restore, as
>   they can be installed in Windows after the successful migration.
>
> Acronis Universal Restore is applicable for:
>
> - Instant recovery of a failed system on different hardware (hard drive controllers, RAID controllers, NIC) (Acronis Universal Restore);
> - Hardware-independent cloning and deployment of operating systems (Acronis Universal Deploy and Acronis Universal Restore);
> - Real-to-virtual and virtual-to-real computer migration for system recovery, testing and other purposes (Acronis Universal Restore).
>
> **(!)** Acronis Universal Restore does not support or install plug and play drivers.
>
> Acronis Universal Restore is required to restore a system to another
>   hardware configuration. It does automatically detect if the HAL should
>   be changed (and changes it) and also installs drivers for HDD
>   controllers and NIC (if they can be found).
>
> If any system-critical driver cannot be found, one will get a warning
>   message during the restoration process.
>
> **(!)** You do not need to have Acronis Universal Restore installed to back up a system. You only need Acronis Universal Restore to restore a
>   system to dissimilar hardware.

Comment: It's unclear to me;  Would this allow for restore of a system which only exists on a harddrive, that is; can it make an image of the system for recovery when the hardware is already failed, as in my case..?

Comment: As far as i can tell from your description the hardware didn't fail, only Windows failed to boot due to the incompatible HAL. I haven't imaged an offline installation yet but using Acronis True Image to image the drive and then the Acronis Universal Restore feature to restore it *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are going to have to reinstall Windows, as it has noticed a change in the motherboard and the Windows 7 license key is tied to the original motherboard.

Comment: The reasons to reinstall Windows in a case like this are for other reasons, the license being tied to the motherboard, isn't one of those reasons.  It is **trivial** to use software to image the existing hdd and restore the hdd on dissimilar hardware.

Comment: fair enough I suppose

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in Windows 98, and as long as the machine would boot with the same drivers already installed for the previous hardware, it would run and let you install any drivers needed for the new hardware.  Since XP (probably NT 4.0, but I have no direct experience with that version), if Windows detects a "significant" hardware change on startup, it'll refuse to boot and require a reinstall.  This will occur even if the same CPU, RAM, and video hardware are carried over to a new motherboard (I've encountered exactly this), and the same appears to be true of Vista and Windows 7.

I haven't used Win8 or later, but it's very likely the same for those, because it's a way for MS to limit your ability to use a single installed OS across upgrades, hence collect more license fees.  FWIW, it probably wouldn't work well unless the new MB, CPU, and video are nearly identical, so reinstalling would be a good idea anyway.

Comment: It is extremely trivial to restore a Windows installation on dissimilar hardware.